# how to synchronise component state with html-input before assertion?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I am trying to test interactions between a components internals and its HTML.

In the following test code, I have an app-component with an input-field, which is linked to an attribute within the component using two-way binding.

Test1 passes with the use of `fixture.detectChanges` and waiting it to be stable. So, in this test the components test-attribute is synchronised with the input-field.

However, test2 fails due to the fact that the compontent has not been updated with the new test-attribute value. So, what am I missing or doing wrong to synchronise the changes before entering into the assertion?

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  test = 'hello';
}

import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {BrowserModule, By} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {ComponentFixture} from '../../node_modules/@angular/core/testing';
import {detectChanges} from '../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3';
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });
  it('test1', () => {
    const inputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
    const el = inputElement.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(el.value).toBe('hello');
    })

  });
  it('test2', () => {
    const inputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
    const el = inputElement.nativeElement;
    el.value = 'test';
    expect(el.value).toBe('test');
    el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.test).toBe('test');
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input [(ngModel)]="test" type="text">
  <p>{{test}}</p>
</div>
```

I took the answer below and looked at the minimal from the answer to get my test to pass. The key seems to have been to move the fixture.detectChanges() to the beforeEach() function.

I believe this was the minimum I needed to include for a passing test, in addition to adding the fixture.detectChanges in the beforeEach. It seems that the done and the fixture.whenStable is not necessary.

```
it('test2', () => {
   const inputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
   const el = inputElement.nativeElement;
   el.value = 'test';
   el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
   expect(component.test).toBe('test');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue with your test is that you never initially call `fixture.detectChanges()` after you set up your `fixture` and `component` in your `beforeEach`.

> Check
>   [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jasmine-blitz-x7mfac?file=app%2Fdummy%2Fapp.component.spec.ts)
>   stackblitz for a working version of your test.

I added a second `beforeEach` where `fixture.detectChanges` is called:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

And here is the failing (now working) test:

```
it('test2', (done) => {
  const inputElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
  inputElement.value = 'test';

  const inputEvent = document.createEvent('Event');
  inputEvent.initEvent('input', true, true);
  inputElement.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);

  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.test).toBe('test');
    done();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second test, you have to add this:

```
el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

before doing the expect, and not after

and then you have also to add

`fixture.detectChanges();` before doing the expect as well

so write your second test like this:

```
it('test2', async(() => {
    const inputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement;
    inputElement.value = 'test';
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.test).toBe('test');
    })
}));
```

**You have to add `async` to your `it` function** because `ngModel` is async.

Alternatively you can use fakeAsync as well

Comment: Thats exactly what I have (I just included an extra assert-statement above). The expect that I have before all of that is not the case for failure.

Comment: The addition of async does not make a difference.

Comment: it will make a big difference, google a little bit ``fixture.whenStable``, you will find that it is all time inside an async block, if it is not working for you , create a demo using stackblitz to show where is your problem

Comment: I have googled quit a bit, and yes. Fixture.whenStable is used a lot in tutorials with code that has an async-block, but I have tested it in my code and that does not solve the problem. I also tried to use call fixture.detectChanges() within fixture.whenStable since I found that in a google search too.

Comment: use ``async(() =>`` and not ``async() =>``, I've updated my code

Comment: I did use async(() => since that is according to what is given in tutorials (for instance testing asynchronous code, angular codecraft). I tried the async test-zone when I tested the fakeAsync, but also the async-syntax for ES2016 javascript to make sure what you meant. I might of course have overlooked something.

Comment: I found an interesting blog (first suggestion when google testing ngModel), which I am exploring.